# Raml to dto or dto to Raml. what should be better?

Tags: java, specifications, raml

From Design perspective, before development what should be the better way before sharing the contract to consumer, creating RAML first and then generating DTOS or vica versa?

Comment: Do you mean DTOs as objects which are returned from your API?

Comment: yes request/response objects.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding there is **no difference** because *both should be done*.

RAML is used to document and define API where DTOs play an important role. Defined resources without proper DTOs is uncompleted API. In the same time resource names, query parameters and some other API details are first things to define, so I would go with defining RAML first. Furthermore, when consumer is on a more complicated level than just fetching the data and has some business logic it could be quite expensive to change the use of API if DTOs are not defined. Thus I would advise to agree on this before hand.

It is not possible to see all the details before API implementation starts, but it is better to spend couple of hours more during technical design phase than couple of days or weeks during implementation phase when API requirements change.

Comment: Yes but the problem is when designing the contract, I experienced a situation wherein the contract was so much prone to changes that creating RAML first was looking not much efficient because everytime i had to change the DTO(adding a new field, return type etc) RAML was needed to change and it felt that I should have created DTOs first and once final raml should be generated.

Comment: Well, I could agree that objects that we pass back and forth are important parts, but I don't think that RAML generation should prevent creating the RAML first. Why is a big problem? I assume that it doesn't take long to generate it.

Comment: Its not a problem but seems inappropriate to ask consumer to regenerate the dtos based on the new raml again and again. Rather, we could wait and create final contract once dtos are finalized.Just a trade-off, nothing is bad though.